# How to deny creating empty log file with be.file in Pantheios?

Tags: pantheios

1)be.file backend has a feature - messages added before _be_file_set_filename() are not lost and will be appended to log later.
2)_be_file_set_filename opens file immediately => if no entries was added, emty file will be created

Question: how to suppress creating empty file (create file only when first log entry appended) and save feature 1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_DELETE_IF_EMPTY`, described [here](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/group__group____backend____stock__backends____file____flags.html).

My guess is that the file is created synchronously to avoid the less-desirable situation where a log file cannot be created while a process is running. If you really want that, maybe add the functionality and supply back to the project?

Comment: That's a solution but `Note:
The current implementation checks the actual file size, as opposed to **"remembering"** whether any writes were made (by Pantheios).`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by writing custom backend - wrapper over be.file